# sql selecting filter and unfilter

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = "SELECT id, 
                user, 
                need, 
                offer, 
                details 
         FROM list 
         WHERE need=$sneed 
            and offer=$soffer 
         ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Here is what I want:

```
$sneed = 1;
$soffer = 2;
```

Will show all records with need 1 and offer 2, and this is ok it's done.

```
$sneed = 1;
$soffer = NULL;
```

Will show all records with need 1 , this is not happening ofcourse, how could I achieve it?

```
$sneed = NULL;
$soffer = NULL;
```

Will show all records. also not happening.
Is this possible ?

Comment: dynamically create your sql

Comment: think about what is **sql** and what is **php** you solve your problem by using different "querys" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$where="";

if($sneed && $soffer)
{
    $where="where need=$sneed and offer=$soffer";
}else if($sneed){
    $where="where need=$sneed";
}
}else if($soffer){
    $where="where offer=$soffer";
}

$query = "SELECT id, user, need, offer, details FROM list $where ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about performance, just fix the logic in the `WHERE`:

```
WHERE (need = $sneed OR $sneed IS NULL) and
      (offer = $soffer OR $soffer IS NULL)
```

If you do care about performance (specifically, the use of indexes on `need` and `offer`), then construct the correct query in the application, using only the clauses you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can add many params as following not only 2

```
 $query = "SELECT id, user, need, offer, details FROM list WHERE 1 = 1 ";

if($sneed){
  $query .= " and need=".$sneed;
}

if($soffer){
  $query .= " and offer=".$soffer;
}

if($anotheroffer){
      $query .= " and anotheroffer=".$anotheroffer;
}
```

Note: don't forget to escape string mysql_real_escape_string() to avoid sql injection.